# Reading folder structure using phonegap for iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, cordova, jqtouch

I am creating one app using phonegap framework.
In that app I want to traverse through all folder structure inside "www" folder.

Can anybody send me some code in JS/JQuery/JQtouch that will work on iphone and ipad?

If anybody want more clarification please let me know.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. 
You have to know the file you're looking for.

See http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File